# How can I set color of specific characters in a cell value of excel for epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

If my cell value is "REGION AND COUNTRY" and I want to only set font color of "**COUNTRY**" or "**TRY**" to red in it then how can do that using **epplus**?
Ex : Worksheet.Cells[1,2].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
This changes the font color of complete cell value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use rich text formatting for that.
This example hardcodes the text without looking at the original contents of the cell, but you could read the cell and split it into runs with individual formatting.

```
            var cell = Worksheet.Cells[1, 2];
            cell.RichText.Clear(); //Incase you're running this multiple times and don't want duplicate text.
            cell.RichText.Add("REGION AND ", false);
            var counRun = cell.RichText.Add("COUN", false);
            var tryRun = cell.RichText.Add("TRY", false);
            counRun.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            tryRun.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```